# Magento 2 Installation Set up Wizard: [ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

Tags: magento2, web-setup-wizard

I am installing **Magento CE 2.3.2**, the installation fails at 24% with the error

> [ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

The full Console Log is below.

I notice that the CPU hits 100% - is that a factor?

AS ever, any advice gratefully received!
Kevin

```
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
Upgrading schema... 
[ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'caferic1_mage.trdemail_campaign' doesn't exist in /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91
Stack trace:
#0 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(91): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(107): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\{closure}()
#2 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(92): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute(Object(Closure))
#3 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#4 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#5 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `trdem...', Array)
#6 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(542): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `trdem...', Array)
#7 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(617): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('DESCRIBE `trdem...', Array)
#8 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(171): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('DESCRIBE `trdem...')
#9 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1668): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('trdemail_campai...', NULL)
#10 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(944): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->describeTable('trdemail_campai...', NULL)
#11 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(970): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->tableColumnExists('trdemail_campai...', 'send_id', NULL)
#12 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php(72): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->addColumn('trdemail_campai...', 'send_id', Array)
#13 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php(421): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeSchema->upgradeTwoOSix(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql), Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup))
#14 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php(49): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeSchema->upgradeOneOneZeoToTwoTwoOne(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext), Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql))
#15 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(984): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeSchema->upgrade(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#16 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(831): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema', Array)
#17 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema(Array)
#18 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#20 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#21 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#22 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#23 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#24 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#25 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#26 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#27 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#28 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#29 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#30 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#31 {main}

Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'caferic1_mage.trdemail_campaign' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `trdemail_campaign` in /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110
Stack trace:
#0 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(92): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute(Object(Closure))
#1 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `trdem...', Array)
#4 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(542): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `trdem...', Array)
#5 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(617): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('DESCRIBE `trdem...', Array)
#6 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(171): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('DESCRIBE `trdem...')
#7 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1668): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('trdemail_campai...', NULL)
#8 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(944): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->describeTable('trdemail_campai...', NULL)
#9 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(970): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->tableColumnExists('trdemail_campai...', 'send_id', NULL)
#10 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php(72): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->addColumn('trdemail_campai...', 'send_id', Array)
#11 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php(421): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeSchema->upgradeTwoOSix(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql), Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup))
#12 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php(49): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeSchema->upgradeOneOneZeoToTwoTwoOne(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext), Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql))
#13 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(984): Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Setup\UpgradeSchema->upgrade(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#14 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(831): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema', Array)
#15 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema(Array)
#16 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#18 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#19 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#20 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#21 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#22 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#23 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#24 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#25 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#26 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#27 /home/caferic1/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#28 /home/caferic1/public_html/setup/index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#29 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a lack of resources on the Server. the CPU topped out and I think the installation tripped over itself.

I have started again on a beefier server and all is good.

Kevin